# Numpy svd vs Scipy.sparse svds

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, svd

I was working on implementing a solver for sparse undetermined systems in Python (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843004/solving-an-underdetermined-scipy-sparse-matrix-using-svd)) and I was trying to rebuild the nullspace function that uses the standard numpy svd function (`numpy.linalg.svd`) in the SciPy [cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html) using the scipy.sparse version of svd (`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`) but it outputs different left and right singular vectors for the examples I ran - including the matrices:

```
[[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1]]  
[[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,1]]
```

Why do these two solvers produce two different svd outputs for the matrices above? What can I do to ensure the same output?

## Edit

Here's an example: *table* is a `csc_matrix` such that

```
table.todense()  = matrix([[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1]],dtype=int64)
```

So, the following code outputs

```
numpy.linalg.svd(table.todense()) =  
[[ -3.64512933e-01   7.07106781e-01  -6.05912800e-01]  
[ -3.64512933e-01  -7.07106781e-01  -6.05912800e-01]  
[ -8.56890100e-01   2.32635116e-16   5.15499134e-01]]  
-----------------------------------------------------
[ 2.58873755  1.41421356  0.54629468]
-----------------------------------------------------
[[ -4.7181e-01 -4.7181e-01 -4.7181e-01 -4.7181e-01 -3.3101e-01]
[5e-01   5e-01  -5e-01  -5e-01 6.16450329e-17]
[-1.655e-01  -1.655e-01  -1.655e-01  -1.655e-01  9.436e-01]
[5e-01  -5e-01  -5e-01   5e-01 -1.77302319e-16]
[-5e-01  5e-01  -5e-01   5e-01 2.22044605e-16]]
```

And the following

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(table,k=2)=  
[[  7.07106781e-01,  -3.64512933e-01],
[ -7.07106781e-01,  -3.64512933e-01],
[  2.73756255e-18,  -8.56890100e-01]]
-------------------------------------
[ 1.41421356,  2.58873755]
-------------------------------------
[[  5e-01,   5e-01,  -5e-01, -5e-01,   1.93574904e-18],
[ -4.71814e-01,  -4.71814e-01,  -4.71814e-01, -4.71814e-01,  -3.31006e-01]]
```

Note that there are quite a few values that overlap between the two solutions. Also, the `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` function doesn't allow k to be greater than or equal to `min(table.shape)`, which is why I chose k=2.

Comment: Could you, please, show an example of input data, how you run these functions and output? It would highly improve this question.

Comment: I would check out the linked question, I explain it better there.

Comment: For both functions, the `singular values` (`s`) is the main thing they promise.  The k largest `s` values match.  SVD is not unique.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD

Comment: [What fast algorithms exist for computing truncated SVD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159325/what-fast-algorithms-exist-for-computing-truncated-svd) looks like a useful answer.  It talks about truncated SVD, and mentions the `ARPACK` implementation, which `svds` also cites.  MATLAB has both `svd` and `svds`.  Also http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2012/singular-value-decomposition-in-scipy/

Comment: Huh interesting. I didn't realize svd was not unique. That definitely throws a monkey wrench into my plans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output in the question you posted looks fine to me. In the numpy call you are calculating every singular value and in the scipy code you are calculating just the top k singular values, and they match the top k from the numpy output.

The sparse top k svd won't let you calculate every singular value because if you wanted to do that, then you could just use the full svd function.

Below I have included code for you to check this out yourself. The caveat is that while the numpy and scipy full svds can both recreate the original matrix well enough, the top k svd cannot. This is because you are throwing away data. Normally this is fine given that you are okay with being close enough. The issue is that SVD if used with top k can be used as a low rank approximation of the original matrix, not as a replacement.

For clarity, my experience on this comes from implementing a python, parallel version of this paper for the original author, [A Sparse Plus Low-Rank Exponential Language Model for Limited Resource Scenarios](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7050385/).

```
import numpy as np                                                                                   
from scipy import linalg                                                                            
from scipy.sparse import linalg as slinalg                                                           

x = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1]],dtype=np.float64)                                 

npsvd = np.linalg.svd(x)                                                                             
spsvd = linalg.svd(x)                                                                                
sptop = slinalg.svds(x,k=2)                                                                          

print "np"                                                                                           
print "u: ", npsvd[0]                                                                                
print "s: ", npsvd[1]                                                                                
print "v: ", npsvd[2]                                                                                

print "\n=========================\n"                                                                

print "sp"                                                                                           
print "u: ", spsvd[0]                                                                                
print "s: ", spsvd[1]                                                                                
print "v: ", spsvd[2]                                                                                

print "\n=========================\n"                                                                

print "sp top k"                                                                                     
print "u: ", sptop[0]                                                                                
print "s: ", sptop[1]                                                                                
print "v: ", sptop[2]                                                                                

nptmp = np.zeros((npsvd[0].shape[1],npsvd[2].shape[0]))                                              
nptmp[np.diag_indices(np.min(nptmp.shape))] = npsvd[1]                                               
npreconstruct = np.dot(npsvd[0], np.dot(nptmp,npsvd[2]))                                             

print npreconstruct                                                                                  
print "np close? : ", np.allclose(npreconstruct, x)                                                  

sptmp = np.zeros((spsvd[0].shape[1],spsvd[2].shape[0]))                                              
sptmp[np.diag_indices(np.min(sptmp.shape))] = spsvd[1]                                               
spreconstruct = np.dot(spsvd[0], np.dot(sptmp,spsvd[2]))                                             

print spreconstruct                                                                                  
print "sp close? : ", np.allclose(spreconstruct, x)                                                  

sptoptmp = np.zeros((sptop[0].shape[1],sptop[2].shape[0]))                                           
sptoptmp[np.diag_indices(np.min(sptoptmp.shape))] = sptop[1]                                         
sptopreconstruct = np.dot(sptop[0], np.dot(sptoptmp,sptop[2]))                                       

print sptopreconstruct                                                                               
print "sp top close? : ", np.allclose(sptopreconstruct, x)
```

Comment: This is quite interesting. Is it possible to calculate the nullspace of a matrix from this truncated svd, or not? If not, are there any full svd solvers for sparse matrices in python?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't believe that you can use a truncated svd to calculate the nullspace as you need all of the singular values. There are two main differences between the sparse version and full version. The full version is faster by a whole factor (O(n^3) v O(n^4), but scales by the size of the matrix in memory requirements. The sparse version scales in memory the number of non-zeros.

In your case, as long at the matrix is not too large, I would use the full version.

You can also look into things like [sparsesvd](https://pypi.org/project/sparsesvd/) if sparse is needed.

Comment: The examples I'm using make it nearly impossible to store the matrix in non-sparse form due to the size of data. Unfortunately, sparsesvd also computes a truncated svd, so I don't really have many options here. Do you know a way to hard code a sparse version of full svd?

Comment: Have you tried passing a sparse matrix to scipy.linalg.svd?

Comment: Yea I have... I got this: Sparse matrices are not supported by this function. Perhaps one of the scipy.sparse.linalg functions would work instead.

Comment: Have you thought about using something other than python? Looking around it seems like R is able to do this. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41259/how-to-compute-svd-of-a-huge-sparse-matrix

Comment: If it has full svd, I'm definitely willing to try it!

Answer (score 3):

```
u,sigma,v = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
```

is equal to

```
u,sigma,v = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(A,k=min(A.shape[0],A.shape[1]))
u = -u[:,::-1]
v = -v[::-1,:]
sigma = sigma[::-1]
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: (This is not to say the above doesn't try to answer `Why do these two solvers produce two different svd outputs` or fails to do so correctly - but, please: explain. Heed [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))